# Twinkle Sparql tool failing

Tags: sparql

I've downloaded Twinkle sparql querying tool but when writing the following query which I obtained from the mondial manual [here](http://www.dbis.informatik.uni-goettingen.de/Teaching/SemWeb/semwebBlatt1ML.pdf), I'm getting an error:

```
prefix mon: <http://www.semwebtech.org/mondial/10/meta#>
prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
SELECT ?N ?P
FROM <file:mondial.n3>
WHERE {?X rdf:type mon:Country . ?X mon:name ?N . ?X mon:population ?P .
FILTER (?P > 10000000) }
ORDER BY DESC(?P)
```

Query Exception Error:

```
com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryException: Unexpected error executing query
```

The error is with the tool, any suggestion on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Try starting Twinkle from the command line. When an error occurs, the application logs more detailed information about the error to the standard output, so make sure you see it.

(For example, the problem may be something as simple as Twinkle not finding the file referred to by `file:mondial.n3` -- the current working directory might not be what you expect; so you may want to provide a file: URI with an absolute path, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

How big is the Mondial dataset?

Twinkle uses ARQ under the hood and loads data into an in-memory dataset in order to query it so it is possible you are trying to load too large a dataset and experiencing a OOM error which Twinkle is hiding from you.

You can try increasing the JVM heap size when you start Twinkle using the standard JVM args for this but if the dataset is particularly big you are not going to be able to load it into the JVM without an awful lot of RAM.  Also for large datasets your query performance is going to be awful with an in-memory dataset.

Comment: its quite big. it contains all countries and many of them cities

Comment: @user1774937 Do you know how many triples?  At the very least what is the size on disk?

Comment: 8.9 MB, here is the site I got it from: http://www.dbis.informatik.uni-goettingen.de/Mondial/

Comment: Ok, given that the file is small then you should follow @Jukka Matilaninen's advice - the problem is likely something mundane such as not finding the data and running in the way he suggests may make it easier to see the problem